# false/null value equivalent for source_policy_documents in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform I have a `aws_iam_policy_document` as follows:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policydoc" {
  statement {
    sid = "denys3access"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

I wish to use this in another `aws_iam_policy_document` but only if `var.env` is not `staging`. I have tried the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "newpolicydoc" {
  source_policy_documents = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.commonpolicy.json,
    var.env != "staging" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.policydoc.json : {}
  ]
}
```

but I get the error

> The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are string and object, respectively.

Then I tried the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "newpolicydoc" {
  source_policy_documents = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.commonpolicy.json,
    var.env != "staging" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.policydoc.json : ""
  ]
}
```

but now the errors shown are

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string

and

> The plugin.(*GRPCProvider).UpgradeResourceState request was cancelled.

I know I could do something like:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "newpolicydoc" {
  source_policy_documents = var.env != "staging" ? [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.commonpolicy.json,
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.policydoc.json
  ] : [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.commonpolicy.json
  ]
}
```

but this could get convoluted as I introduce more resources that are dependent on the values of certain variables. Does anyone know a more concise way (in line with my earlier attempts) that would allow me to add resources based on the values of variables?

Comment: Does `var.env != "staging" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.policydoc.json : jsonencode({})` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JSON data from the data source, adding an empty map as a value if the result in the ternary operator is `false`, i.e., if the variable `env` is equal to anything else than `staging`, will not work, as type of data has to match. To fix this, you can use [`jsonencode` built-in](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) function to convert the map to a JSON data structure:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "newpolicydoc" {
  source_policy_documents = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.commonpolicy.json,
    var.env != "staging" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.policydoc.json : jsonencode({})
  ]
}
```